# how to automatically expand detail in kendo grid for angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am having a problem with automatically expanding the details in kendo grid using angular. I want to be expanded details when datas load. I am using the ng-template kendoGridDetailTemplate. Is there any way to automatically expand detail?

I have tried using kendoGridCellTemplate just input text, but it can't load datas.

`<kendo-grid [data]="boxList" >
 <kendo-grid-column field ="BOX_NO" title="box_no"> </kendo-grid-column>
<ng-template kendoGridDetailTemplate let-dataItem>
 <p>{{dataItem.ETC}}</p>
</kendo-grid>`

I wanted them to show automatically expanded. Not clicking the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

1. In your code add a viewchild to be able to access the grid

   ```
   @ViewChild(GridComponent) private grid: GridComponent;
   ```
2. In the ngOnInit do the following

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < this.boxList.length; i++){
    this.grid.expandRow(i);
   }
   ```